# Конструктор с параметрами в конструкторе наследуемого класса

Tags: c++, visual-studio

пишу в хэдере следующее:

```
class publication {
protected:

    string  nazv;
    float cost;

    publication() : nazv("xx"), cost(0) {

    }
public:
    publication(string a, float b) : nazv(a), cost(b) {

    }
    void getdata();
    void putdata();
};

class book:publication {
public: 
    void getdata();
    void putdata();
protected:
    int str;
    book() : publication(), str(0) {

    }
    book(int c) : publication(string a, float b), str(c) {

    }
};
```

и VisualStudio выдает ошибку в объявлении второго конструктора в наследуемом классе - подчеркивает красным `string a`, `float b` и говорит, что что-то не объявлено. Вопрос - как правильно вызывать этот конструктор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом конструкторе

```
book(int c) : publication(string a, float b), str(c) {
                          ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^
}
```

в списке инициализации вы можете вызывать конструкторы базовых классов, передавая им выражения. Вы же используете спецификаторы типов, как будто бы объявляете параметры.

Правильно было бы записать

```
book(string a, float b, int c) : publication(a, b), str(c) {
}
```

Или

```
book(int c) : str(c) {
}
```

Также вам следует в базовом классе объявить деструктор виртуальным. Например,

```
class publication {
protected:
    virtual ~publication() {}
//...
```

И возможно функцию

```
void getdata();
```

лучше объявить как константную функцию класса, так как она не изменяет состояние объекта класса

```
void getdata() const;
```

Также вероятно лучше объявить эти функции

```
void getdata();
void putdata();
```

также виртуальными в базовом классе

```
virtual void getdata() const;
virtual void putdata();
```

Так как класс `publication` имеет защищенные конструкторы (кроме конструктора копирования), то рассмотрите вариант сделать этот класс абстрактным.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ и советы по организации классов.

Comment: @derzz Не за что. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что именно Вы хотите сделать, но видимо вот это:

```
book(string a, float b, int c) : publication(a, b), str(c) {}
```

В списке инициализации должны быть только *вызовы* конструкторов, параметры конструктора должны быть в описании конструктора.